# What's the best place to hide long lived encryption keys

Tags: security, encryption

I am considering encryption options for a new Sybase project. I am thinking that Sybase encryption is the wrong strategy because a) dba's can get in, and b) if and when we migrate to SQL Server or Oracle I don't want to deal with different encryption strategies.

Therefore I'm thinking to encrypt the sensitive data (symmetric encryption) in my Java code before storing it in the DB.

Now, the encrypted fields better not have their encryption key changed, ever, except in a very controlled environment, which for me effectively means never. So it's going to be a permanent password.

The question is, where should I keep this password in a way that it is accessible from the program but not accessible to anyone else. If it's in a properties file, any developer with access to our Git repo could see it.

We could hard code it in the source code, but good lawd, that's a bad practice.

We could generate it in source, like the 10th Fibonacci or 3!+8! that would be hard to locate, but it's still rather exposed.

We could have the sa's maintain it in the environment, but then where do they file it for future reference?

So many poor choices. Are there any good ones?

Comment: [Put it in a properties file, but list this file in `.gitignore`.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly a programming problem.  It's more of a security design question, and I believe it would be more appropriate on the [Information Security](//security.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @TobySpeight it really is a programming question. I will reword it, but my main question is "where do you store these passwords securely so that the program can access them but no person can"

Comment: Don't you hate when people vote you down without leaving a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using some secret code to create the key on the fly is both an insecure method and produces a poor key. The DB keep needs to be a random byte array. Keep in mind that the key needs to be in memory when used which will be most of the time for the DB.

WRT using the DB encryption, examine closely if the algorithm is fully specified and compatibility to another DB. There is also the possibility that the entire DB will need to be run-off and then added to a new DB, in that case using the internal DB encryption will be transparent.

You really need to consider needing to be able to change the encryption key in the future, what will you do if it is ever compromised? There are solutions to this dilemma. There may be a substantial performance penalty performing the encryption outside the DB, there is a substantial setup time for each new encryption operation. Also since not all columns will be encrypted (a good guess) that information is not shared by the DB and the outside encryption code, that coupling is not good for design nor maintenance.

Do not connect the DB server to the Internet, make it separate and connected with a non-networked connection such as direct Ethernet. This also limited the number of admin users of the only system that contains the encryption key.

Another important part of the solution is to restrict admin access to the server. This includes requiring two-factor authentication as well as severely limiting the number of administrators. You need to control the second-factor to physical serial-numbered devices owned by the organization so that they can be positively retrieved on personnel changes and not copied. Personally I favor RSA SecureID (or similar) hardware devices, there is positive control.

Finally in answer to the question, keep the key in a file on the DB server secured as above, that is with no Internet access and restricted admin access.

Comment: Some notes and questions. This is an internal application, the DB is behind our intranet.  Not all columns require encryption. Actually all sensitive stuff is in one column of a single table, nobody has access to the prod DBs except for production services. But the company has a requirement that sensitive data must be encrypted, so if the key is kept in the DB it will be available to the DBA's and so it is essentially not encrypted

Comment: If you are trying to conceal the encryption key from system admins there is little hope. If the data is relatively small there is the option of procuring an external device (HSM or similar) that contains the key and also performs the encryption/decryption thus the key is never available and then only that device must be administrated securely. It is also possible to have dual-custody so that no one individual can obtain access to the device. Prices starting at around $500 ranging up to $100K, a lot depends on the required thru-put: entry size * entries/minute.